# Regular expression for 10 digits or 11 digits

Tags: regex

Can anyone let me know the meaning of below regular expression patterns?

```
Pattern p1=Pattern.compile("^1?(\\d{10})");
Pattern p2=Pattern.compile("^1?([1-9])(\\d{9})");
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Off the top of my head, these look like regular expressions to match US phone numbers.

The first one matches a number comprised of either 10 digits, or 11 digits if the first number is 1.

- `1?` — optionally match a 1
- `\d` — match a digit between 0 and 9 (escaped as `\\d` in Java)
- `{10}` — match the preceding character 10 times (in this case, a digit)

The second one matches the same pattern, with the exception that the first (or second, if 1 is present) digit cannot be a 0.

- `1?` — optionally match a 1
- `[1-9]` — match a single digit between 1 and 9
- `\d` — match a digit between 0 and 9 (escaped as `\\d` in Java)
- `{9}` — match the preceding character 9 times (in this case, a digit)

Note that both expressions begin with `^`, which simply means "match only at the start of the line". Also note that parentheses, as used here, are used for *capturing* groups of characters, but do not affect the meaning of the expression.

Comment: Pattern p1=Pattern.compile("^1?(\\d{15})");  does this match a 15digit number which compulsarily does not starts with 0

Comment: It matches a 15-digit number that doesn't start with 1, or a 16-digit number that does. The `?` means optional. If you did `"^1(\\d{14})"`, *that* would match a 15-digit number which compulsorily starts with 1 (a [non-optional] 1, followed by 14 other digits). If you want an expression that matches 15 digits where the first is nonzero, it would be `"^[1-9]\\d{14}"` (and you can optionally throw some parentheses around the parts you want to capture).

Comment: It might be helpful to know that `"\\d"` expands to `"[0-9]"`, so the expression I gave in the previous comment could just as easily be written `"^[1-9][0-9]{14}"`, which makes it pretty clear that it's "a digit between 1 and 9, followed by 14 digits between 0 and 9".

Answer (score 3):

For explaining regex, you can always use [this online explainer](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5Cd%2B%28.%5Cd%2B%29%3F%28%5BeE%5D%5Cd%2B%29%3F)

The output for your regexes:

```
Regex: ^1?(\d{10})

NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1?                       '1' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{10}                   digits (0-9) (10 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

```
Regex: ^1?([1-9])(\d{9})

NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1?                       '1' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [1-9]                    any character of: '1' to '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{9}                    digits (0-9) (9 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
```

Answer (score 0):

First regex:

`^` - beginning of line or string
`1?` - character `1` zero or one repetition
`\d{10}` - ten digit characters

Second regex:

`^` - beginning of line or string
`1?` - character `1` zero or one repetition
`[1-9]` - any digit character except `0`
`\d{9}` - nine digit characters